# @Transactional in a service class with no call to database

Tags: spring, spring-transactions

When a service class has no implementation of Jpa repository ,My understanding is that it is wrong to annotate it with Transactional, for example this service class with should not have @Transactional

```
@Service
public class BillingAddressServiceImpl implements BillingAddressService {

    public BillingAddress setByUserBilling(UserBilling userBilling, BillingAddress billingAddress) throws DataAccessException

    {
        billingAddress.setBillingAddressName(userBilling.getUserBillingName());
        billingAddress.setBillingAddressStreet1(userBilling.getUserBillingStreet1());
        billingAddress.setBillingAddressStreet2(userBilling.getUserBillingStreet2());
        billingAddress.setBillingAddressCity(userBilling.getUserBillingCity());
        billingAddress.setBillingAddressState(userBilling.getUserBillingState());
        billingAddress.setBillingAddressCountry(userBilling.getUserBillingCountry());
        billingAddress.setBillingAddressZipCode(userBilling.getUserBillingZipCode());

        return billingAddress;
    }

}
```

Comment: You are right. It makes no sense.

Comment: you have a different opinion why ? @LovaChittumuri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Transactional` annotation stands for declaring the database transaction handling of Spring bean methods.

Since your service method is not working with the database it makes no sense to declare a transaction handling.

Answer (score 0):

Transactional annotations are only used with method or classes that makes calls to database,one of the uses of transactional annotation is rollback - which means when we make call to a database there would be a recording of the intermidiate state between the successful call and its original state, this is so that in the case of a failed call the system does not crash but is able to return to its original state